# Combining EVALUATE with VLOOKUP in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup, evaluate

I'm trying to perform a series of VLOOKUPs in VBA and figured that there must be a way to do it in batch with the EVALUATE function, rather than loop through the values on the sheet individually (which I already know how to do). But I'm struggling with making the lookup value "dynamic".
This is what I've got so far:

```
Dim ws1 as worksheets, ws2 as worksheet, rngJ2 as Range, Lastrow2 as long

Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

 LastRow2 = ws2.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=Range("A1"), _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row

set rngJ2 = ws2.range("J2:J" & Lastrow2)
```

Now here is what I want to do next, knowing that the rngJ2.address(row) part is not the correct syntax:

```
rngJ2.Value= Evaluate("VLOOKUP(Sheet2!I" & rngJ2.address(row) & ",Sheet1!A:H,8,FALSE)")
```

What I'm trying to do with the rngJ2.address(row) part is defining the appropriate row for each cell in the range so that Cell J5 uses I5 as the lookup value, J12 uses I12, etc.

Any ideas?

Comment: Range rngJ2 will have multiple rows, the first criterion of Vlookup is a singe cell.

Comment: Are you putting the VLookUp results into a column?  If so you can enter the formula into the first one and use a Range.FillDown to quickly use the formula over multiple rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't any need for `Evaluate` there at all. You can use the `Worksheetfunction` version instead:

```
rngJ2.Value = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(rngJ2.Offset(, -1), Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:H"), 8, False)
```

Comment: I didn't manage to think of that offset trick, but  it's exactly what I was looking for. I was unaware that VLOOKUP could be assigned to a whole range like that, so thank you!!!

Comment: It is possible to get VLOOKUP to play ball with `Evaluate` using multiple cells in the lookup value part, but it takes some additional constructs, so this is a **lot** simpler!